# '==' operator for column headers?

Tags: r

consider the following:

```
canada <- c(10, 20, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(20, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.min, " is ", score.min, " cents. ", "\n\n"))

  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  score.max <- c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.max, " is ", score.max, " cents. ", "\n\n"))
  }
```

Above script leads to this:

```
> price("canada")
In Canada, an apple is 10 cents. 

In Canada, an orange is 90 cents.
```

I wanted to find out if affordable apple comes from Canada, so I added this:

```
if(name.min == myrow[1])
  cat("If name.min is 'apple', then it should print. But, it does not?",
      "Affordable apples come from", nation, ".")
if(name.min != myrow[1])
  cat("If name.max is not 'apple', then it should print. And, it does.")
```

Altogether, full script is:

```
canada <- c(10, 20, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(20, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.min, " is ", score.min, " cents. ", "\n\n"))

  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  score.max <- c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.max, " is ", score.max, " cents. ", "\n\n"))

  if(name.min == myrow[1])
    cat("If name.min is 'apple', then it should print. But, it does not?",
        "Affordable apples come from", nation ".")
  if(name.min != myrow[1])
    cat("If name.max is not 'apple', then it should print. And, it does.")

  }
```

Which prints the following:

```
> price("canada")
In Canada, an apple is 10 cents. 

In Canada, an orange is 90 cents. 

If name.max is not 'apple', then it should print. And, it does.
```

My speculation is that the first option *if(name.min == myrow[1])* does not print because it is comparing alphabets with numbers. The second option *if(name.min != myrow[1]* prints because it is true that alphabets are not numbers.

Am I making the correct speculation here? If so, what would be the alternative method to replace myrow[1]?

Comment: Your `name.min` is `null`.The vector obtained from `fruit[,val]` does not have names. So look into that

Comment: @Onyambu, following your hint, I may have found the answer. Would you mind taking a look at my correction below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aim is to find out the country which produces the affordable fruit type:

I have written a simple code for you:

```
price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[,val]

  nations <- names(myrow)[which(myrow==min(myrow))]

  #Icould have used which.min, but that will give me just one country in   case there
  #are more than one country which has affordable  val.
  art = ifelse( grepl("[aeiou]",substring(val,1,1)),"an","a")
       #This is the article to be placed before the fruit ie "an" or "a"

  nations <- tools::toTitleCase(nations)

  cat(paste0("In ",tools::toTitleCase(names(myrow))," ",
         art," ",val," is ",myrow, " cents.","\n\n"),sep = "")

  if(length(nations)>1) nations = paste(nations,collapse = " and ")
   cat( "Affordable",paste0(val,"s"),"come from", nations, ".")

}
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
 price("apple")
 In Canada an apple is 10 cents.

 In Korea an apple is 60 cents.

 In Iran an apple is 20 cents.

 Affordable apples come from Canada.

 price("banana")
 In Canada a banana is 20 cents.

 In Korea a banana is 30 cents.

 In Iran a banana is 20 cents.

 Affordable bananas come from Canada and Iran.

 price("orange")
 In Canada an orange is 90 cents.

 In Korea an orange is 90 cents.

 In Iran an orange is 40 cents.

 Affordable oranges come from Iran.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Onyambu's hint, I think I may have found the answer:

```
canada <- c(10, 20, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(20, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.min, " is ", score.min, " cents. ", "\n\n"))

  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  score.max <- c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  cat(paste0("In ", nation, ", an ", name.max, " is ", score.max, " cents. ", "\n\n"))

  if(name.min == names(myrow[1]))
    cat("If name.min is 'apple', then it should print.",
        "Affordable apples come from", nation, ".", "\n\n")
  if(name.min != names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))])
    cat("If name.max is not 'apple', then it should print. And, it does.")

  }
```

Thank you very much for pointing me towards the right direction.

```
> price("canada")
In Canada, an apple is 10 cents. 

In Canada, an orange is 90 cents. 

If name.min is 'apple', then it should print. Affordable apples come from Canada .
```

Comment: According to the desired objective, your function does not give the correct solution. How does it know the prices of apples in other countries yet you only give it one country??.For example: `price("iran")` This says tha affordable apples come from `Iran` and `price("Canada)` says affordable apples come from Canada.. so which is correct? ? You need to write a function that takes in a fruit and not the country. It then be able to tell you the country that gives you the most affordable price for that specified fruit.